# Does Tkinter come with File Dialogs by default?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, tkinter

I've been reading the TKDocs [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html), looking at the section Windows and Dialogs. One part provided various ways to save, open and locate files on the hard drive.

```
from Tkinter import filedialog
dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

After trying one however, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    a()
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 2, in a
    from Tkinter import filedialog
ImportError: cannot import name filedialog
```

The code provided in the docs are done with Python 3. I've only modified the `import` on Tkinter (uppercase vs lowercase).

My question is:

Are filedialogs in `Tkinter` somewhere else, or are they something that you need to get online, or are they not provided at all? I have python 2.7.6.

Comment: Yes, it's called `tkFileDialog`

Comment: `tkFileDialog`? I will try that now. :)

Comment: Yep. It worked. And it has everything. I feel stupid now...

Comment: @Jkdc Do add an answer which the OP can accept! (I had typed in in editor before you FGITWed it)

Comment: @BhargavRao Go ahead with yours, I hadn't typed one up yet :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `tkFileDialog` from Tkinter package. Refer [this](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog)

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
```